# Changing UINavigationBar Font Type while keeping the default size

Tags: ios, fonts, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I know that for changing the font of `UINavigationBar` he will simply do

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "MavenProBold", size: 15)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Tho, i'm trying to change only the font type, and keeping iOS default font size(which i guess he is dynamic among the devices).
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the font type, you will have to specify a font size. Generally you have to do this manually.

If you want to match the size of another font you see, say in another `UILabel`, you could do:

```
CGFloat fontSize = self.label.font.pointSize; // obj-c
let fontSize = CGFloat(label.font.pointSize) // swift
```

And then assign the size of the font you are setting to be this.

**UPDATE**

After thorough investigation, the common font size of the `UINavigationBar` is 34px, which is 17 in your Xcode editor. Remember that you can manually override this view, but that is the default font size.

Comment: The problem is that i can't get the default font value of the navigation bar.

Comment: So you can refer to this: http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-7-design-cheat-sheet/ but this is hardcoded, and I know you're trying to get something dynamic, let me keep looking. AFAIK the font size is hard coded, keeping with proportions amongst size classes, but I'd like to double check.

Comment: We need to find a way to access to UILabel of the title. Maybe this is the way to go?

Comment: I checked it out and I am not able to access the `titleView` property on a standard `UINavigationController` set in a storyboard with a standard text title. I know you can override this with a new view but it doesn't look like you can access it's properties.

What I do know is that, on all iPhones, the font size will remain the same. It might change for iPad, but that's it. You'll have to set it manually I'm afraid.

Comment: I've managed to do so :  print(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes)

Comment: Let me know if you have any new thoughts

Comment: Ok that's great, let me try this and then I'll update my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109461/discussion-between-dokun1-and-roi-mulia).